# Refresh page and go back to date where you are

Tags: fullcalendar

When I refresh my page, the calendar returns to today's point.
How can I change this, so if I refresh the page that the calendar is on the day I am at that time.
For example, today is 3/25/2021 I will go to 7/28/2021 I refresh the page and then I will be back on 3/25/2021. That's not what I want, I want to refresh the page and go to date 7/28/2021 automatically

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you are using to manage your component? Right now you are not sharing enough details for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the calendar view changes (there's a [callback you can use](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks) to detect that), store the calendar's current date somewhere (e.g. perhaps in localstorage, or in the server-side session, or something). Then you can re-use that to set the initial date option on the calendar when you re-load it.